# I am trying to send mail which will redirect the content of log files in logfile.txt in same directory.But its failing

Tags: linux, bash, ssh

Please find my script below:-

```
#!/bin/bash
date=`date +%Y%m%d`

ssh root@server-ip  "ls -lrth /opt/log_$date/"

ssh root@server-ip  "cd /opt/log_$date/; for i in `cat *.log`;do echo $i >> /opt/log_$date/logfile.txt; done;cat  /opt/log_$date/logfile.txt| mail -s \"Apache backup testing\" saranjeet.singh@*****.com"
```

Any help will be appreciated. Thanks

Comment: Can you write more about what you're trying to do. A lot of your script doesn't make much sense (1st ssh line isn't doing anything, unless you're redirecting it outside)

Comment: In first line I am just checking that its showing list of directories or not.. But in second line "echo $i" will not redirecting content of log files to logfile.txt. This is the main issue.Thats why it sending empty mail to me.

Answer (score 1):

Because you use double quotes, your backticks are getting evaluated on the local host before the SSH command executes.

A much better fix in this case is to avoid them altogether, though;

```
ssh root@server-ip  "cat /opt/log_$date/*.log |
     tee /opt/log_$date/logfile.txt" |
mail -s ...
```

Comment: I refactored the `mail -s` to run on the local host, but maybe you have your reasons to want to run that on the remote host? The revert should be trivial.